# Azure DevOps Manage Existing Environments

Tags: azure-devops

I have the Project Administrator access and build admin access in my ADO project but unable to edit/select the environments (in the release pipeline stages) someone else has created. So, if the project administrator can't do this, who else can grant permission to administer all the existing environments?